# how to pull email from <td> in php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

From the following HTML i need to extract email address only to save it in database. I need to pull it in array, what i was planning is to use jquery/ajax to pull all email using dom and save it to another page using ajax ,but the problem is that 
`<td>` have no unique identification with other `<td>` i.e i can do it if td has class or id name

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <table width="100%" border="1">
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME</td>
      <td>ADDRESS</td>
      <td>PHONE</td>
      <td>EMAIL</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>wwqw</td>
      <td>qww</td>
      <td>ew</td>
      <td>email@exmaple.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>wew</td>
      <td>ew</td>
      <td>emai1l@exmaple.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>ewe</td>
      <td>we</td>
      <td>email2@exmaple.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>we</td>
      <td>we</td>
      <td>we</td>
      <td>emai3l@exmaple.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ww</td>
      <td>w</td>
      <td>w</td>
      <td>emai4l@exmaple.com</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I need to grab email address and store in array like below

```
Array
(
    [0] => email@exmaple.com
    [1] => emai1l@exmaple.com
    [2] => email2@exmaple.com
    [3] => emai3l@exmaple.com
    [4] => emai4l@exmaple.com
)
```

`<td>` can have variable  class and id , so its very hard to use jquery etc to pull them. I am obstructed by it . Any help wil be appreciated

Comment: Can you tell us how you plan to use jQuery to fill a PHP array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not  use jquery, regular expression  will make your job easy.

```
$string='<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<table width="100%" border="1">
<tr></tr>
<tr>
  <td>NAME</td>
  <td>ADDRESS</td>
  <td>PHONE</td>
  <td>EMAIL</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>wwqw</td>
  <td>qww</td>
  <td>ew</td>
  <td>email@exmaple.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>e</td>
  <td>wew</td>
  <td>ew</td>
  <td>emai1l@exmaple.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>e</td>
  <td>ewe</td>
  <td>we</td>
  <td>email2@exmaple.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>we</td>
  <td>we</td>
  <td>we</td>
  <td>emai3l@exmaple.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>ww</td>
  <td>w</td>
  <td>w</td>
  <td>emai4l@exmaple.com</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>';
echo "<pre>";
$pattern="/([\s]*)([_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*([ ]+|)@([ ]+|)([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+([a-zA-Z]{2,}))([\s]*)/i"; 
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery-->

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tr').find('td:last').each(function(){
        var t = $(this).text();
if(typeof(t) === 'string' && t.indexOf('@') >-1) alert(t);
    })
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
    include('simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <table width="100%" border="1">
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME</td>
      <td>ADDRESS</td>
      <td>PHONE</td>
      <td>EMAIL</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>wwqw</td>
      <td>qww</td>
      <td>ew</td>
      <td>email@exmaple.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>wew</td>
      <td>ew</td>
      <td>emai1l@exmaple.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>ewe</td>
      <td>we</td>
      <td>email2@exmaple.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>we</td>
      <td>we</td>
      <td>we</td>
      <td>emai3l@exmaple.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ww</td>
      <td>w</td>
      <td>w</td>
      <td>emai4l@exmaple.com</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>';

    $dom = new simple_html_dom();
    $dom->load($html);
    $table = $dom->find('table', 0);
    if($table){
        foreach($table->find('tr') as $row) {
            $rowData = array();
            foreach($row->find('td') as $cell) {
                $rowData[] = $cell->innertext;
            }
            $theData[] = $rowData;
        }
        print_r($theData);
    }
?>
```

Or you can do it with jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tr').find('td:last').each(function(){
        console.log($(this).text());
    })
});
```